# How to add custom validation on checkout page before shipping method rendering in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, custom-validation

How to add custom validation on checkout page before shipping method rendering and if validation success then only show shipping methods or else show error message.

I have already implemented this but using preference shipping.php overriding the issue is that it is calling for each shipping method (degrading module efficiency and message is showing on other page not on same checkout page)

Here is my git repo on dev branch

https://github.com/gauravnewton/Excellence_UkOnly/tree/dev

also i am applying some validation on product attributes and shipping address's country code

see in my **model/shipping/shipping.php** file

Comment: solved by my self overrided core's files to list only my desired shipping methods into my module